# How to Draw a Smoother Path

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

I have a program that allows the user to select a size and draw a freeform curve, similar to a pen function for a graphics program. I am using `Path2D` for this.

I'm looking for a way to make the drawn path less jagged. Originally I had used `path.lineTo` for this function, resulting in the jagged path on the left. Then I tried `path.curveTo`, but this produced a variety of pointed areas along the path as seen on the right.

[image: jagged path][image: jagged and pointed path]

Is there a way to make curves smooth with `Path2D`?

```
import ...

public class Test extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    int count, midX, midY, curveX, curveY;
    Point startPoint, stopPoint, releasePoint;
    Shape pathShape;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (pathShape != null) {
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(50));
            g2.draw(pathShape);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) {
        count = 1;
        startPoint = new Point(ev.getPoint());
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        pathShape = path;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {
        releasePoint = new Point(ev.getPoint());
        Path2D path = (Path2D) pathShape;
        path.moveTo(releasePoint.x,releasePoint.y);
        path.closePath();
        pathShape = path;
    }

    // The mouseDragged method where lineTo is used.
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) {
        stopPoint = ev.getPoint();
        Path2D path = (Path2D) pathShape;
        path.moveTo(startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
        path.lineTo(stopPoint.x,stopPoint.y);
        pathShape = path;
        startPoint = stopPoint;
        repaint();
    }

    // The mouseDragged method where curveTo is used.
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) {
        if (count == 2) {
            midX = stopPoint.x;
            midY = stopPoint.y;
        }
        if (count++ >= 3) {
            curveX = midX;
            curveY = midY;
            midX = stopPoint.x;
            midY = stopPoint.y;
        }
        stopPoint = ev.getPoint();
        Path2D path = (Path2D) pathShape;
        path.moveTo(startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
        if (count >= 3)
            path.curveTo(curveX,curveY,midX,midY,stopPoint.x,stopPoint.y);
        else
            path.lineTo(stopPoint.x,stopPoint.y);
        pathShape = path;
        startPoint = stopPoint;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(50, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
```

instead of `g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(50));`

Comment: Thanks. I kept thinking it had to do with the path, not the stroke of the Grapics2D object.

Comment: By the way... I understand the fact that SO is not a code dump - I've seen comments saying so many times. I try making my example minimal, complete, and verifiable. What is wrong with this one? Sure, it's a little lengthy, but it is complete, I've included the parts of the program that demonstrate the issue (without any other unnecessary code), and it runs fine without any errors. Can you provide your feedback so that I can improve future questions?

Comment: It won't compile or run, it's missing the reaming logic for the `MouseListener`s, doesn't have a `main` method...it's not "complete" or "verifiable" :P - Which left me to "guess" at the problem

Comment: I understand. I intentionally left out the other `MouseListener` methods and the `main` method for the sake of keeping it minimal since the code would be rather lengthy if I had included them, assuming (probably incorrectly) that others would know that they should be included. Although everyone's view of an MCVE is different, should I include these pieces of information next time (though if so, it wouldn't exactly be "minimal" in my view)?

Comment: Look towards making the smallest possible example/demo you can that accurately demonstrates what you are doing and the problem you are having. This way, if we can't see the problem in the code, we can dump into a IDE and run it ourselves and tweak and debug to see how to fix it :P